# Why can't my [TestMethods] reference the browser I made in [test initialize]?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

In my selenium webdriver Unit test, I have a `[TestInitialize]` section at the top, just to setup the browser which recurs in all tests and isn't very pretty.

My problem is, in the actual `[TestMethod]`'s themselves, the Chrome browser I set up in the Initialize (i.e. variable name "d") - is not being recognized. When I hover over "d" in the test method, it says "the name 'd' does not exist in the current context."

I gather that I am making a rather elementary error here, can someone explain, in simple way, what I am doing wrong (and hopefully, what I should be doing)?

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestSetup()
{
    IWebDriver d = new ChromeDriver("C:\\location\\of\\my\\chrome_driver\\is_here\\");
    d.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
    d.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}

[TestMethod]
public void ClickTrumpet_LouieArmstrongMusicPlays()
{            
    d.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://bupitybop.kom/");

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        d.FindElement(By.ClassName("boopi-boopi")).Click();
    }
    d.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d` is declared in the scope of `TestSetup()`. It will not be available outside of `TestSetup()`. In order to fix this, make it an instance variable so it has scope throughout the whole test class.

```
IWebDriver d;

[TestInitialize]
public void TestSetup()
{
    d = new ChromeDriver("C:\\location\\of\\my\\chrome_driver\\is_here\\");
    d.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
    d.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}

[TestMethod]
public void ClickTrumpet_LouieArmstrongMusicPlays()
{            
    d.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://bupitybop.kom/");

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        d.FindElement(By.ClassName("boopi-boopi")).Click();
    }
    d.Quit();
}
```

Comment: So simple ! Yes, I get it ! And it works. An "instance" variable! Thanks so much E. Moffat for contributing to these early baby steps in my programming knowledge :) Regards, Yan :)

Comment: PS- I understand Stackoverflow is about being straight to the point, and thus that this comment will soon be deleted. I just wanted to register to whoever's reading that I do not think the word "thank you" (or as I put it, "Thank you kindly" is so offensive/distracting that it needs to be edited out ! I don't seem to have permission to write this anywhere but here, thank you for reading - you may delete now. Best, Y.

Comment: @Yan No offense was intended. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts - I think its the preference of the community that these parts of posts be edited out.

Comment: --None taken, I mean that ( and appreciate the link ) - thanks again for your help with my issue :)